# Mr Beer Fermentor Leaking

Tags: fermentation, spoilage

Found an old Mr Beer kit that had never been used. The malt and yeast that came with the kit had expired, so I bought replacements. I followed the directions in the booklet, and put the fermenter in a cabinet.

When I checked a few hours later, a small amount of liquid, maybe half an ounce, was coating the bottom of my cabinet. I put the fermenter on a rimmed cookie sheet, and it is still leaking very slowly, less than an ounce a day.

Should I just toss it? Wait until bottling and see if it's bad? Should I try to fix it somehow? The leak is very slow, so it's hard to tell where it's coming from, and I don't want to mess with it too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are:

**Leave it:** You have already put the effort in to make the brew so I would say just leave it until it is ready to bottle.

**Buy a second fermenter:** then transfer the remaining beer to it after it has been cleaned and sterilized.

**Fix the leak:** Depending on the size of the leak you could try to stem the flow with either vasonline, tape it up, use silicone (you would need to check the chemicals and make sure it is food safe), or try to plastic weld it with a soldering iron.

If it was me I would leave it as it will only be 1 week or so in the fermenter so you shouldn't loose too much. If you find that you are then buy another fermenter.

Answer (score 1):

The original Mr Beer has holes in the top half that let air out, there was no airlock. So you could have filled it higher than designed and with a vigorous fermentation some yeast leaked out.

You can tape paper towels to the outside to see where the leak is, but if it's on top then it may be by design. if not, as suggested use "food grade" silicone.

The Mr. Beer is a great two gallon fermenter. I love small batch beer, because you can brew 5 gallons quicker in your kitchen and requires far less equipment. The spigot is very convenient. I heard you can buy them for 10 dollars on the mister beer site, but they have airlocks now.

Have fun. Check out Brooklyn Brewshops "beer making book" they have one gallon recipes you can double for the mr beer fermenter.